# Simple.data with stored procedure that returns multiple result sets

Tags: simple.data

Is there a way to execute a stored procedure that returns multiple result sets with simple.data and how do you defferenciate between the two sets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use SimpleResultSet.NextResult() to access the next results set.

Comment: Hello Sam, here is one suggested edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2911886 Can you update your answer according to it? ;)